# Static classes overview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, oop, c#-4.0

I read some articles about static classes but I have some questions:

1. Where take static classes place in memory?
2. According to [C# Static Methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-method) : `means that you want the declaration to refer to a single location` If I use static classes in Asp.Net is it mean I have a location that share between all requests?
3. I read in the articles that static classes and static methods are faster that instance-oriented classes,so why I don't see them in every where.I mean in .Net there is a few static classes and methods exist too.

Comment: Stick to SO for knowledge, don't Bing around for sites that obviously contain FUD like "static classes and static methods are faster". :)

Comment: If so please give me(and other who don't knew much about static classes) some reference about that.thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

> Static classes are loaded automatically by the .NET Framework common
>   language runtime (CLR) when the program or namespace containing the
>   class is loaded.

So it means that the static classes are loaded in memory. This mean that you would not like that all your classes are loaded in memory when your process starts.

2.Static classes in asp.net are saved in application state, so yes, you have a location that share between all requests. 
Static methods are useful in asp.net but only if you don't use static objects inside of the methods  because you may get in trouble with different threads accessing modifying the same vaiable.

3.If you use a lot static classes they will be loaded in memory and that's not necesarly something you would want.

See this link for more information:
[static variables in asp.net/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536680/static-variables-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: greate @Dorin.in No. 3, by having huge RAM is that importatnt that all classes will load?

Comment: Yes ram memory it's necessary. But don't forget to pay attention that if you work with database it is not recommended to use static classes to connect to it, because it will keep your connection open from the time the connection opens at application load to the point that you application closes.

Comment: This is almost correct. The CLR doesn't initialize the static fields of a class until any of the static or instance members of that class is accessed. It doesn't happen when the app is started or the assembly is loaded.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx ; I took this information from MSDN. Static members are initialized when they are accessed, but static classes are initialize when the assembly is loaded.